Deveikut and bitachon are different concepts but seem to overlap - what's the relationship between them?
Bitachon means trusting that God will take care of things. Deveikut means an awareness or feeling of God's presence. It seems to me that a person who is practicing deveikut will automatically and necessarily have bitachon; however, the reverse is not necessarily true. Is this a correct understanding?

Take a look at the Meshech Chachma on the verse ובו תדבק, who writes at length about this connection.

@MichoelR it seems clear to me that this stunning Meshech Chachma agrees with the specific question by OP, i.e. that clinging is the highest form of bitachon, so it's indeed possible to have bitachon without clinging, but not the other way around (and that clinging will automatically produce sublime bitachon). Want to write it up? LFE, check it out for yourself: https://www.sefaria.org/Meshekh_Chokhmah%2C_Ekev.28?vhe=Riga,_1927&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

@RabbiKaii Can't do it for a while, so go ahead if you want.
